# How can I add a list of intergers together using a comprehension?

Tags: python, sum, list-comprehension

I'm trying to convert a number to a string, then to a list, then converting the list of numbers into integers, then adding these numbers together.

Here's an example:

```
Number = 123456789
SplitList = (list(str(Number)))
IntergerList = list(int(I) for I in SplitList)
A = 0
A = (A + S for S in IntergerList)
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Are you trying to do `sum(int(ch) for ch in str(Number))` ?

Comment: What's your expected end result vs what you're actually getting?

Comment: I don't see a single list comprehension. Also, list comprehensions *are for creating lists*, not for summing the values in the list. They are not just shorthand for writing a for-loo. You should just use the built-in `sum` function, but essentially, the operation you are looking for `reduce`

Comment: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x1022eb4b0>

Comment: Jorge, those are *generator* comprehensions, not list comprehensions.

Comment: Let's say I had:
    SplitList = (list(str(Number))) and wanted to sum the list of strings together. Is it possible using comprehensions?

Comment: @JonClements: golfed ya: `sum(map(int,str(number)))` :)

Answer (score 4):

Why reinvent the wheel? Just use the built-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function:

```
sum(integerList)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why transform it to a list? This is a math problem, do the maths :), it's another option just only another:

```
Number = 123456789
res = 0
while Number:
  res += Number % 10
  Number //= 10
```

res = 45

Or with `divmod` like:

```
Number = 3332
res = 0
while(Number != 0):
  parts = divmod(Number, 10)
  res += parts[1]
  Number = parts[0]

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by passing a generator expression to the builtin function `sum`.

```
number = 123456789
sum(int(digit) for digit in str(number))
```